# IIS Express Multiple Sites Appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I seem to have multiple sites defined in my applicationhost.config file which is located inside the .vs folder of my solution.

The sites are like this

```
<site name="WebUI(2)" id="4">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\...\WebUI" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1234:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44359:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44359:local.someDomain.co.uk" />
                </bindings>
            </site>

<site name="WebUI(3)" id="5">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\...\WebUI" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1234:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44359:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44359:local.someDomain.co.uk" />
                </bindings>
            </site>

<site name="WebUI(4)" id="6">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\...\WebUI" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1234:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44359:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44359:local.someDomain.co.uk" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

IIS express seems to be running MySite(3) however these are all copies of the same site and having (3) in the name seems really ugly.

If I simply removing WebUI(3) from the config file then IIS refuses to start and Visual Studio throws an error saying:

`The process with id:<PID here> is not running.`

I'm not sure how to clean this up. I have tried searching the internet but nothing seems to address this issue.

Comment: "having (3) in the name seems really ugly. " It is not a file for human to read, so leave it as it is.

Comment: @LexLi but I am having to edit it because of some interesting URL Rewrites that are going on in a project that I've inherited. The previous developers are no longer with the company so I can't ask for their advice either.

Comment: Site name is a metadata for IIS configuration only. No URL rewrite rules should ever use site name. So I don’t know what you are talking about.

Comment: @LexLi I am trying to set a http binding but IIS Express keeps creating new site tags every time I update the settings. These new site tags lack the binding so I have to manually keep recreating it.

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html You keep breaking the sync between your project file and IIS Express config file, and that's why Visual Studio (and only the latest builds) keeps adding the necessary elements back to prevent you from seeing an error. So if you truly want to solve the problem, edit both files and keep them in sync.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you

Comment: So the issue was resolved?

Comment: @LexLi not really but at least I understand why it's happening.

Comment: @K-Dawg I know this is from forever ago, but did you ever figure out a way to clean this up? I am experiencing the same thing since I edited one of the ports to point to a different domain than localhost. Whoops...

Comment: @MKF I can't remember what happened yesterday let alone three years ago but you could try deleting the .vs folder? I think it should regenerate everything for you and maybe clean it up?